# How to extend my national visa in Poland by one day?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, overstaying, poland

I am currently in Poland on exchange for one semester and my visa period which covers 138 days in total will end on the 30th June. However, on that day Beyonce will have a concert in Warsaw which I would like to attend very much. Considering the hours of the concert i will have to buy a ticket for the 1st July. Is there anything to do to (legally) extend my permit of stay by one day,  so I won't have any problem on the border when leaving.

Comment: Go see her in Berlin on the 28th. Sorted.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/79143/3221

Comment: What's your nationality?

Answer (score 2):

You have a national D visa which ends on June 30th. So you need a Schengen visa (that means **any** Schengen visa) for July 1st and perhaps a few days more.

- Apply for a Polish D visa. Probably impractical.
- Apply for a Polish C tourist visa. Not sure how they will react.
- Apply for a C visa from another Schengen state. To do that you would have to have *genuine* travel plans which take you there after your studies in Poland so that the other state is the main destination.