Returning to Sweden while waiting for permit extension. Entering Schengen through another EU country
I'm a non-EU national from a country with visa free travel to EU for short tourist stays,
I have a Swedish work permit that expires in December, my employer will apply for an extension.
I am planning to travel outside of Schengen in November while my work permit card is valid and return in January,
In January, my work permit extension application will either be in progress or granted, but in either case, I will not have a valid work permit card,
I'm planning to travel from Sweden via another Schengen country and return via same route,
I understand from this answer, that as long as extension application is made, the work permit is valid, regardless of what it says on the work permit card https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/182270/174288
This page from Migrationsverket mentions that in my situation, business travel is permitted, but it's not clear regarding personal travel, https://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/Working-in-Sweden/Frequently-asked-questions-about-work-permits.html
Can anyone share their experince or knowledge on whether I will be able to enter Schengen when I come back in January? Also, what documents should I have with me to prove that I have the right to enter?

What country are you exiting and re-entering Schengen through? You need to contact that country and ask

Germany issues a temporary document confirming that you've applied for a residence permit with 3 checkboxes for why you applied. 2 of them disallow re-entering the country (you're supposed to wait inside Germany until you get a decision), 1 of them (renewal, your case) allows re-entering the country. Do you know if Sweden issues such a document? If it helps, we call it the "Fiktionsbescheinigung".

I think Sweden can only give you a confirmation that you have submitted the application for extension. With an internal reference number

@noob643 Again, what country are you flying through?

@Crazydre I will be flying through Netherlands.

@noob643 Amsterdam? If so email immigration at hoofd.doorlaatpost.gb@mindef.nl, attach an image of your document from Migrationsverket, state your nationality, and ask if they'll let you back into Schengen under these circumstances

The TIMATIC database used by most check-in staff does NOT mention the extension letter as a visa exemption.
You'd be fine to fly to Sweden directly from outside Schengen, because of your visa-free nationality.
As for your actual question - whether you can fly to another Schengen state - I there's no official information on that. Contact the relevant immigration authority and ask
