# I want to travel Europe after my study visa expires: can I do this on a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, long-stay-visas, 90-180-visa-rules

I have a study visa for 10 months (duration of the course) and entered EU using this visa. I want to travel right after my course on a Schengen visa. Is this possible or do I need to exit Europe for 180 days to do so?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79143/how-to-switch-from-resident-visa-to-tourist-visa-status-in-the-schengen-area

Answer (score 1):

Stay within the Schengen area under a long term visa (like your 10 month study visa) does not count for the purposes of the 90 days in 180 calculation. [See here, and in particular the user's guide for the short stay calculator](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing_en).

> Periods of stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall not be taken into account in the calculation of the duration of stay on the territory of the Member States

Assuming you a citizen of a Schengen visa-waiver country, you are free to leave Schengen at the end of your long stay visa, and then immediately seek readmission for a short stay (although it might not be advisable to try and reenter the country which issued your long-stay visa, since they may suspect you are trying to continue residence). If you are not a citizen of a Schengen visa-waiver country, you would of course need to apply for a short stay visa before reentering.