# Work visa expiring, can I stay as a tourist?

Tags: visas, overstaying, long-stay-visas, working-visas

I'm a citizen of Argentina residing in France with a long-stay visa for an internship, valid from September 5th 2018 until January 5th 2019. As an argentinian, I'm allowed to visit Europe as a tourist for up to 3 months without any kind of visa.

Can I stay after my visa expires, by "using" those days, or must I leave on that date? What if I exit the Schengen area and then reenter as a tourist?

I'd only stay for a a few days, about 3, but I guess it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen Given that their nationality allows them to leave and then immediately re-enter without a visa, it's not at all unreasonable for a non-expert to wonder whether the leaving is necessary. They're trying to understand the rules, not 'flout' or 'rewrite' them.

Comment: I rephrased to make what I'm really asking clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What if I exit the Schengen area and then reenter as a tourist?

Yes you can do that. You must exit before or when your visa expires. Go somewhere else and then make your visa free entry request. Whether they let you in or not is just speculation at this point but if you are able to convince them to let you in, there is no rule you're breaking.

Comment: Thanks! So I must really leave? In that case I probably won't do it, I just want to book a flight on the 7th instead of the 5th.

Comment: I believe you must.

Comment: Is there no "waiting period" to re-enter Schengen under a different visa? Can OP literally go to the Schengen border, cross out of Schengen, then turn around and re-enter as tourist for the 90 days?

Comment: Nope, none that is known to public: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79143/how-to-switch-from-resident-visa-to-tourist-visa-status-in-the-schengen-area