# 90 days as tourist after visa expires

Tags: visas, schengen, 90-180-visa-rules, working-holiday, chilean-citizens

I have a working holiday visa from September 19th 2019 to March 22nd 2020 for Poland. I would like to stay here for 90 more days as a tourist. I traveled to Ukraine during Christmas 2019 for 1 week and then came back to Poland, and they gave me the stamps for entering the Schengen zone.

If I leave the Schengen zone again will I somehow keep my days as a tourist in Poland? I want to travel back to Ukraine before my visa expires.

Comment: Im from Chile, i have a Visa until march 22nd. My last entry to Poland was on december 27th from Ukraine

Comment: So my tourist days are covered by my visa? Sorry i just wanna make sure

Comment: Your Polish visa is irrelevant to anywhere except Poland. If you travel to another Schengen country while your Polish visa is valid, your days in that country count towards the 90/180 days visa-free stay for which you are eligible due to your citizenship. The Ukraine isn’t part of Schengen, your stay there is governed by the immigration rules applicable to Chilean citizens.

Comment: This question relates to switching from a long-term visa to visa-free status https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79143/how-to-switch-from-resident-visa-to-tourist-visa-status-in-the-schengen-area Is that What you’re really asking about?

Comment: I would like to know if i can stay in Poland for 90 days as a tourist after that my visa expires

Comment: You can stay for 90 days providing you don’t go to another Schengen country meanwhile. You can check how many days you can stay here https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en It is typically a wise approach to plan to leave Schengen a few days before your visa-free period expires rather than on the 90th day itself.