# Staying after residency permit expires - Sweden

Tags: schengen, sweden, residency

My residency permit for Sweden expires on the 17th of  June, but I am wanting to stay for longer after this date.  Can I utilise the 90 day rule from the 17th and on, or do I have to leave Sweden on this date?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch from Resident visa to Tourist visa status in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79143/how-to-switch-from-resident-visa-to-tourist-visa-status-in-the-schengen-area)