# Remaining in Poland for 3 weeks after expiration of student visa

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, tourist-visas

I am an American student having been in Poland on a student visa since the middle of September. My visa expires on June 30th. I am going back to the US in August to renew the visa. I am meant to take a three week course in Poland in July. I am confused if the 90 day window is applicable to me. I called the consulate but received no information. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Which consulate? Why you should go back to US to renew the visa? I'm little confused. If you want to use the 90 day rule, you should check that you are following the condition for such rules. I'm not sure full time student is an allowed activity on such time. Do not overstay. A ban will remain on your travel history (and for many countries) for a lot of years. Try to find a way to ask extension directly in PL

Comment: As a citizen from a visa-free country, you can stay up to 90 days after a long-stay visa.

This problem has been addressed in the answers to this question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79143/how-to-switch-from-resident-visa-to-tourist-visa-status-in-the-schengen-area and this question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-long-term-visa-ends-in-schengen-countr

Specifically interesting to you would be this answer: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/35406/95392

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi US citizens have very favorable conditions on temporary residence permits in Poland. IIRC, they can stay there longer than the 90 Schengen short stay visa free days under Polish national law.