# Can I re-enter Germany after visa expires?

Tags: schengen-visas

I'm from the UK and entered Germany on September 6th 2022, and got a residency permit on the 20th of November 2022. My visa expires on the 31st of May, and I am wondering if I go back to the UK after my visa expires, will I be able to re-enter Germany again right away (June 1st or 2nd) or will I have to wait 180 days?

Comment: Is your residence permit currently valid?

Comment: With 'My visa' do you really mean 'My residence permit'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch from Resident visa to Tourist visa status in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79143/how-to-switch-from-resident-visa-to-tourist-visa-status-in-the-schengen-area)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume your residence permit is currently valid.  In this case, you do not need a visa and your presence in Germany is not limited to 90 days in any 180-day period.

If you do not have a valid visa or residence permit and your 90/180 limit is fully exhausted then you must remain outside the Schengen area for 90 days (not 180) to reset it fully.  (You may be able to return sooner for a shorter stay than 90 days depending on your recent travel history.)

Comment: I think the OP is mixing up the terminology and really asking what happens when the **residence permit** expires on the 31st of May. This is where The Border Guard handbook (page 42 of PDF) comment comes into play: *National rules or practices which lay down that a third-country national must as a general rule leave its territory after termination of a long-stay (covered by a residence permit or national visa) before being allowed to start a subsequent short-term stay on that territory are not compatible with Schengen rules.*

Comment: If that is the case, the OP could then stay in the Schengen Area 90 days starting on the 1st of June.