# Travelling within the Schengen region either side of my long stay student visa in Italy?

Tags: schengen-visas, italy, australia, student-visas

I’ve gotten some mixed responses from the Italian consulate here in Italy vs. the Italian consulate in Australia here.

I’ve been on a study visa for 6 months in Italy and my student visa is about to expire. I’ve assumed (I hope correctly) that either side of this visa type D, I can travel for up to 90 days within the Schengen region given I hold an Australian passport. The reply from my consulate back home said:
‘*Australian citizens holding a long-stay national visa may spend a further 90 days in any of the Schengen country in any 6 month period as tourists ONLY prior, during or after the validity of their national visa.’*

I’ve had the immigration / police here say that I need to fly back home as soon as my study visa expires here. I explained the Schengen border code (another post mentioned it on here) and Australians travelling in the Schengen region for 90 days but they weren’t interested in listening! Also my Italian is not fantastic!

Any advice would be great. I’ve made all these plans after my student visa to utilise my Schengen 90 travel…!

Comment: See answer to: [Italian student visa, withdrawing from classes - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/180268/95267). The immigration/police should read the  **Practical Handbook for Border Guards**: *National rules or practices which lay down that a third-country national must as a general rule leave its territory after termination of a long-stay (covered by a residence permit or national visa) before being allowed to start a subsequent short-term stay on that territory **are not compatible with Schengen rules**.*